# Suggestions for HLSL 2D shader tutorials?

Tags: resources, 2d, hlsl, pixel-shader

I am looking for some resources for writing *2D* shaders (*not* 3D, so please no references to vertex shader code or anything like that). I'm using [HLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_shader_language), but having a lot of trouble finding good tutorials.

Any suggestions?